# Is there a batch program that can open one XLSM file, process it, save the file, close the file and then open another XLSM file?

Tags: excel, sequential

I have three xlsm files that I'd like to batch process sequentially (i.e. a.xlms, b.xlms, c.xlms)

They are contained in "c:\xlsm_batch" folder

I've used this batch code to run the files and it WORKS .... BUT DOES NOT save them or close them once they have been run sequentially.

@echo off
for %%x in (C:\xlsm_batch*.xlsm) do (
echo Starting.. %%x
start "" /wait %%x
)

Is there a way to program this into the code (i.e. saving each sequential XLSM file, closing each sequential XLSM file and then opening up a NEW XLSM file for processing?)

Thanks, R

Comment: A batch file has no ability to manipulate the file in Excel once it's been opened, so you can't do it from the batch file.

Comment: You can run a VBA macro automatically when a workbook is opened, that may help. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late on this answer but I used a combination of task scheduler, batch files and macro's to open files at month end, update the data, save and close then save a copy in another folder for users to access.

---

**VBA within each file**

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))
ActiveWorkbook.Save


ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
```

---

**Batch file**

```
@ECHO ON

'Open Original File

Call "C:\FileStoredHere\FileName.xlsm"

'Close all open instances of Excel

taskkill /f /im Excel.exe

'Copy to User Folder

Copy /y C:\FileStoredHere\FileName.xlsm "\\servername\CopyFolder\FIleName.xlsm"
```

---

One thing worth noting was I couldn't get mapped drives to work for the copy so use the full UNC file path.